# why i'm getting name 'kind' is not defined in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I try to run this:

```
data.loc[data.label == 'spam', 'body_len'].plot(kind == 'hist', bins == bins, alpha == 0.5, normed == True, label =='spam')
```

Following error occurs:

```
NameError: name 'kind' is not defined
```

Comment: Please format your question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this;

```
data.loc[data.label == 'spam']['body_len'].plot(kind='hist', bins=bins, alpha=0.5, normed=True, label='spam')
```

The correct syntax is to use one `=` for parameters in a function.